# json and line break

Tags: ajax, json

I hope, there is a solving of my question. But I can't find it.
Problem: ajax return data with line break (\n). The data must be insert into textarea and will be update from ajax.

I can replace '\n' when reading data (myJsonData.replace.() ... etc). The main problem: how to ready data for textarea to display in correct format with line break?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of the returned data and what you'd like to see instead?

Comment: Try explaining your problem with _at least one entire sentence_ rather than just a sentence fragment.

Answer (score 0):

just replace it to something revertable, like `-=br=-` and when insert to the textarea, replace back to `\n`

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with line breaks in textarea and you just can insert the data as is. But if you still have problems with special chars - you can encode your JSON data and decode it on insert.